# I cannot determine whether my apache2 installation is prefork or worker (multithreaded) by the output of apache2 -l

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, apache2, worker

I am expecting to see either prefork.c or worker.c but I see neither.  My output is below.  How can I tell what I'm running?  I also do not see the standard configuration parameters for prefork and worker in my apache2.conf - very confused.

> root@www:/home/manuel# apache2 -l
>   Compiled in modules:
>    core.c
>    mod_so.c
>    mod_watchdog.c
>    http_core.c
>    mod_log_config.c
>    mod_logio.c
>    mod_version.c
>    mod_unixd.c

What am I running here exactly and how do I optimize it?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.4, MPMs can be dynamically loaded.

You must use apacehctl -M to list all of the dynamically loaded modules, not just the static ones listed with -l.

Comment: Thanks that was it.  I think you meant apachectl -M though.